# Convert Strings of a dictionary to int

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary loaded:

```
{'17.0x6.0x7.0 6.0': ['4.60x4.30x4.30 4.00, 4.60x4.30x4.30 1.00, 4.60x4.30x4.30 3.00'],
 '9.5x5.5x5.5 1.0': ['4.60x4.30x4.30 5.00'],
 '22.0x7.5x8.0 10.0': ['6.60x6.00x5.16 8.00, 9.00x6.00x5.60 6.00'],
 '17.0x6.0x7.0 6.0_1': ['8.75x6.60x5.60 7.00'],
 '9.5x5.5x5.5 2.0': ['4.60x4.30x4.30 2.00']}
```

I want to extract  the float values after dimensions

Desired output:

```
{6:[4,1,3],
 1:[5],
 10:[8,6],
 6:[7]
 2:[2]}
```

I tried this to extract the dimensions

```
loaded_items = {int(float(k.split()[1])): [int(float(j.split()[1])) for i in v for j in i.split(",")] for k,v in loaded.items()}
```

but this gives me output as such:

```
{6: [7], 1: [5], 10: [8, 6], 2: [2]}
```

i.e when it encounters the second similar object it replaces the value.

I tried one more method:

```
all_items_loaded = {}
for k,v in loaded.items():
    a = k.split()[1]
    print(a)
    for i in v:
        x = i.split()
        x = x[1::2]
        all_items_loaded[a] = x
```

and the output is:

```
{'6.0': ['4.00,', '1.00,', '3.00'],
 '1.0': ['5.00'],
 '10.0': ['8.00,', '6.00'],
 '6.0_1': ['7.00'],
 '2.0': ['2.00']}
```

Comment: What should be done with the duplicate `6.0`?

Comment: your desired output has duplicate keys (`6`), which isn't possible with python dicts. which very well explains your concern: _when it encounters the second similar object it replaces the value_

Comment: is really that the input dictionary? if it really has `'17.0x6.0x7.0 6.0_1'` key your code should crash

Comment: @Tomothy32 I had no idea that the keys name cannot be same, is there any solution for this ?

Comment: Do you want to combine them so `6` maps to `[4, 1, 3, 7]`?

Comment: @Tomothy32 No actually 6 that would kill the purpose

Comment: @Tomothy32 6 is the truck_id, can we replace the int with string but I think dictionaries again won't allow the same string as keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are problems with your data and the required output.

The input dict contains a key  '17.0x6.0x7.0 **6.0_1**'. While calling int(float()) on '6.0_1' works (it is cast to 6.01 and subsequently to 6) I would not recommend this and rather investigate the reason why this data is supplied in this way.

The desired output dict contains duplicate keys. This is not possible and causes the overwriting you are describing. Change your output data structure from dict to e.g. list of dicts.

```
[{int(float(key.split()[1])): [int(float(val.split()[1])) for val in value[0].split(",")]} for (key,value) in a.items() ]
--> [{6: [4, 1, 3]}, {1: [5]}, {10: [8, 6]}, {6: [7]}, {2: [2]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You either need to decide on a different way of associating the data or choose a different data structure to use. One example, a `defaultdict`, is below. This is **not** the only solution and getting a better input would be the first priority.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
d['6.0'].append([7])
d['6.0'].append([4,1,3])

print(d['6.0'])

# result [[7], [4, 1, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The only suggestion I can make (aside from getting a better input) is to create tuples. Create a simple function to extract values from strings:

```
>>> def extract(v): return int(float(v.split()[1]))
```

And apply this function to dictionary key-values pairs and produce a list of pairs:

```
>>> loaded_items = {
...     '17.0x6.0x7.0 6.0': ['4.60x4.30x4.30 4.00, 4.60x4.30x4.30 1.00, 4.60x4.30x4.30 3.00'],
...     '9.5x5.5x5.5 1.0': ['4.60x4.30x4.30 5.00'],
...     '22.0x7.5x8.0 10.0': ['6.60x6.00x5.16 8.00, 9.00x6.00x5.60 6.00'],
...     '17.0x6.0x7.0 6.0_1': ['8.75x6.60x5.60 7.00'],
...     '9.5x5.5x5.5 2.0': ['4.60x4.30x4.30 2.00']
... }
>>> data = [(extract(k), [extract(v) for v in vs[0].split(",")])  for k, vs in loaded_items.items()]
>>> data
[(6, [4, 1, 3]), (1, [5]), (10, [8, 6]), (6, [7]), (2, [2])]
```

You can then group the values if needed:

```
>>> d1 = {}
>>> for k,v in data: d1.setdefault(k, []).extend(v)
>>> d1
{6: [4, 1, 3, 7], 1: [5], 10: [8, 6], 2: [2]}
```

Or:

```
>>> d2 = {}
>>> for k,v in data: d2.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
>>> d2
{6: [[4, 1, 3], [7]], 1: [[5]], 10: [[8, 6]], 2: [[2]]}
```